# Rails (3.2) asset pipeline - is it possible to have condition by the current pipeline entry point?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have multiple asset pipeline apps using common resources. I need these resources be tweaked according to which app required them, for example to have inlined asset or not accordingly.

For example:

**application.rb**:

```
config.assets.precompile +=  %w( app1.js app1.css )
config.assets.precompile +=  %w( app2.js app2.css )
```

**app1.js**

```
 *= require blabla1
 *= require common
```

**app2.js**

```
 *= require blabla2
 *= require common
```

I want to have different results according to the current pipeline entry point
e.g. something in the spirit of the following:

**common.js.erb**

```
var src="<%= currentAssetPiplineEntryPoint == 'app1' ? image_path('img.png') : asset_data_uri('img.png')%>"
```

Doable?
If not, is it because its a bad practice?

Thanks